# how to solve that Sudden Error in css of website page that appeared

Tags: html, css, jsp

I was working on my website and testing it but suddenly the page's css didn't appear and the browser giving my this error.

[image: Screenshot for the browsers error]

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling cache in the network tab in the inspect element and refreshing the page. And also this appears to be a common issue on Firefox try running it from another browser.

Comment: same on edge and chrome